# how to implement animation textField on two pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I implement this kind of animation textField? and also this should be on two pages. (same as a gif). When user click back button/system back button should be back to the previous page.

I got from Facebook app, please check
[image: click here to view sample]

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer, I used `Hero` and `PageRouteBuilder`

*If anyone know a better way, please let me know*

```
class TextScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Hero(
            tag: 'text',
            transitionOnUserGestures: true,
            child: Material(
              type: MaterialType.transparency,
              child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      PageRouteBuilder(
                        transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
                          return NewPage();
                        },
                        transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) {
                          return Align(
                            child: FadeTransition(
                              opacity: animation,
                              child: child,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Hero(
            tag: 'text',
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white70, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
              child: Material(type: MaterialType.transparency, child: TextField()),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```